# How do I add increment to two specific properties of a class?

Tags: javascript

**Here are my instructions, I am having issues with getting two properties 'numberOfLikes' and 'comments' to use increment to adjust the amount of likes and comments. I don't know if I should use a for loop or if I just need the increment operator. I'm new to coding and apologize in advance.**

/*
In the space below, add to the existing skeleton of a Tweet class.

- A tweet should have a (dynamic) author, content, timeStamp, numberOfLikes, and comments.
- A tweet should be able to **increment the numberOfLikes and add to the list of comments.**

Create several instances of your Tweet and log them to the console. Make sure the
tweet object instances *behave* as expected.
*/

```
class Tweet {
    constructor(author, content, timeStamp, numberOfLikes, comments) {
      this.author = author;
      this.content = content;
      this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
      this.numberOfLikes = numberOfLikes;
      this.comments = comments;
 }
};


//This is code I was playing around with, doesn't work

this.add = function(numberOfLikes){
  for(i = 0; i < numberOfLikes.length; i++){
    console.log("You have " + numberOfLikes + " likes");
  }
}

this.add = function(comments) {
  for(i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
    console.log("You have " + comments + " comments");
  }
}



var tweet1 = new Tweet("Rihanna", "Fenty Beauty", "12:31 A.M.", 120193, 6782);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the class body you need to define prototypal functions like this:

```js
class Tweet {
  constructor(author, content, timeStamp, numberOfLikes, comments) {
    this.author = author;
    this.content = content;
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    this.numberOfLikes = numberOfLikes;
    this.comments = comments;
  }
  like() {
    this.numberOfLikes++;
  }
  comment(comment) {
    this.comments.push(comment);
  }
}

const tweet1 = new Tweet("Rihanna", "Fenty Beauty", "12:31 A.M.", 120193, ["I hate I hate know-it-alls"]);

console.log(tweet1.numberOfLikes);
tweet1.like();
tweet1.like();
console.log(tweet1.numberOfLikes);
console.log(tweet1.comments);
tweet1.comment("I love you Rihanna!!")
console.log(tweet1.comments);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: "...add to the *list* of comments..."

Comment: @JordisBurns no problem, just please mark the question as answered if you don't have any further questions so people don't waste their time trying to write an answer for an already answered question

Answer (score 1):

> A tweet should be able to increment the numberOfLikes

This should be a function to increase the **numberOfLikes**.

> and add to the list of comments.

**comments** is probably an array. This means that you need a function to add a comment, to the list of your **comments**.

```
class Tweet {
    constructor(author, content, timeStamp, numberOfLikes, comments) {
        this.author = author;
        this.content = content;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        this.numberOfLikes = numberOfLikes;
        this.comments = comments;
    }
    increaseNumberOfLikes() {
        this.numberOfLikes++
    }
    addComment(commentText) {
        this.comments.push(commentText)
    }
};

let tweet1 = new Tweet("The Weekend", "Some content", "15:31 P.M.", 9800, ["so cool", "do it again"])
tweet1.increaseNumberOfLikes()
tweet1.addComment("Great Song!")

console.log(tweet1)
```

You should create more tweets like above.

Answer (score 1):

You can create functions that use [`+=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment) and [`array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to increment numbers and add values to arrays.

**Incrementing tweets:**

```js
incrementLikes(increment = 1) {
  this.numberOfLikes += increment
}
```

**Adding a comment to the array:**

```js
addComment(comment) {
  this.comments.push(comment)
}
```

I also noticed that in your post you mentioned that `this.comments` was a list. So I made that change when initializing the class.

```js
new Tweet("Rihanna", "Fenty Beauty", "12:31 A.M.", 120193, ["amazing", "wow"]);
```

**Demo:**

```js
class Tweet {
  constructor(author, content, timeStamp, numberOfLikes, comments) {
    this.author = author;
    this.content = content;
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    this.numberOfLikes = numberOfLikes;
    this.comments = comments;
  }
  
  incrementLikes(increment = 1) {
    this.numberOfLikes += increment
  }
  
  addComment(comment) {
    this.comments.push(comment)
  }
};

var tweet1 = new Tweet("Rihanna", "Fenty Beauty", "12:31 A.M.", 120193, ["amazing", "wow"]);

tweet1.incrementLikes()
console.log(tweet1.numberOfLikes)

tweet1.incrementLikes()
console.log(tweet1.numberOfLikes)

tweet1.addComment("This is a comment")
console.log(tweet1.comments)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You need to put the function definitions **inside** the class definition. I also modified the function names, because they conflict with each other.

```
class Tweet {
    constructor(author, content, timeStamp, numberOfLikes, comments) {
      this.author = author;
      this.content = content;
      this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
      this.numberOfLikes = numberOfLikes;
      this.comments = comments;
 }

  addLikes(numberOfLikes){
    this.numberOfLikes += numberOfLikes
  }

    addComments(comments) {
      this.comments += comments
  }
};


// Initial tweet instance
var tweet1 = new Tweet("Rihanna", "Fenty Beauty", "12:31 A.M.", 120193, 6782);

// Call modifiers
tweet1.addLikes(5)
tweet1.addComments(7)

// Check the variables were modified
console.log(tweet1.numberOfLikes)
console.log(tweet1.comments)
```